# Class file not found in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Following [this](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-file-upload-with-validation/) tutorial on how to make uploads in laravel, encountered the following error `Class 'App\Models\File' not found`
When typing `php artisan serve` in the terminal the server works fine but when you upload a file it throws the error mentioned above

I followed the steps carefully and checked `File.php` , `FileUpload.php`

`FileUpload.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\File;


class FileUpload extends Controller
{
  public function createForm(){
    return view('file-upload');
  }

  public function fileUpload(Request $req){
        $req->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt,xlx,xls,jpg,png,pdf|max:4096'
        ]);

        $fileModel = new File;

        if($req->file()) {
            $fileName = time().'_'.$req->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = $req->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');

            $fileModel->name = time().'_'.$req->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileModel->file_path = '/storage/' . $filePath;
            $fileModel->save();

            return back()
            ->with('success','File has been uploaded.')
            ->with('file', $fileName);
        }
   }

}
```

App\Models\File.php

`File.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFilesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('file_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('files');
    }
}
```

I get the error at line 20 in `app/Http/Controllers/FileUpload`

Comment: update your controller for upload file also

Comment: @WailanTirajoh can you be more elaborative

Comment: look, I just want to see your controller. Cause a case like this happens many times at controller, so it would save a lot of time for people to help you, okay?

Comment: your controller looks good, can you provide your File at App/Models/File.php?

Comment: Your problem is that you are not defining its `namespace`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you create a model called File.

here the artisan code to create the model

```
php artisan make:model File -m
```

Comment: i did and i got a migration file in the `/database/migration/`  but still facing that problem

Comment: are you sure our called model in the controller in the right way?

Comment: use App\Models\File;
you have added this one on your controller?

Comment: i tried using `App\Models\File;` but still got the error

Comment: I just want to see your model

Comment: you wrote the wrong code on your model. you have written code for migration. Check the reference link and make the code clear

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class File extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'file_path'
    ];
}

Comment: `<?php namespace App\Models; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; class File extends Model { use HasFactory; protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'file_path' ]; }` this code?